# Inequality between infinite product and infinite sum

Tags: inequality, infinite-product

I was reading a paper which seemed to use (without proof) several instances of the following relation:
$$
\prod_{n = 0}^\infty \left(1 - \frac{1}{f(n) \cdot g(n)}\right)^{f(n)} > 1 - \sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac{1}{g(n)}.
$$
where $f, g\colon\mathbb{N} \to (1, \infty)$ and the right side is greater than $0$.

Is this in fact always true? If so is there a straightforward proof of it? If not are there straightforward conditions which guarantee it holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\prod_{n=0}^\infty\left(1-\frac1{f(n)g(n)}\right)^{f(n)}>\prod_{n=0}^\infty\left(1-\frac1{g(n)}\right)>1-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{g(n)}$$ where the first inequality is basically [Bernoulli's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality), and the second one follows from $$\prod_{n=0}^N(1-a_n)>1-\sum_{n=0}^N a_n\qquad(N>0, 0<a_n<1)$$ which is easy to show using induction (on $N$).